# WCF IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply does work on Asynchronous calls

Tags: wpf, wcf, wcf-client

I have a message inspector in my WPF/WCF 4.0 application that is working great for synchronous calls, but doesn't work at all when I make the calls asynchronous (i.e. use the `proxy.Begin<MethodName>` notation).  Is this expected or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being related to how I was adding headers on the server side.  I was adding them in an operation invoker before I was calling the invoke method.  I changed this so it called the invoke and then added the headers.  After this it worked great.  Not sure why this is, but it solved my problem.